# how do i get the solution for following error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2019, macos-catalina

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly `System.Web.Entity`. Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by code, you may get compilation errors."

I got this error when suddenly started visual studio from WindowsOS to mac OS. 
Is there any solution, anyone knows for this error?

Comment: Check your `packages.config` or `web.config` to make sure there is a reference to it in there. If not check your references in the solution to see if it exists in there. If it exists in one but not the other or perhaps doesn't appear at all. You can either go to the nuget manager and restore it or install it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix: Use the NuGet package `System.Web.Http.Common` instead of `System.Web.Entity`